# Webview set overrideurl not in use

Tags: java, android-studio

Im trying to use the shouldOverrideUrlLoading to handle some tel: links on my webview, but i get this error:

error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

How can i fix that?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private WebView myWebView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.loadUrl("https://**************/");
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            final ProgressBar Pbar;
            Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pB1);
            myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
                {
                    if(progress < 100 && Pbar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
                        Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    Pbar.setProgress(progress);
                    if(progress == 100) {
                        Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                        myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                    }
                }
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecated")
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        view.reload();
                        return true;
                    }

                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });


        }




    }
```

the override is grayed out but i cant figure how to fix it, im not very familiar with java and its driving me crazy, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** in the **WebChromeClient** that you are trying to override.

You can override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading of WebChromeClient as it is present in it

Comment: is there any similar to overrides for WebChromeClient ?

Comment: or any other way to enable tel: links on WebChromeClient?